# Wordpress date update after new post

Tags: wordpress

I've been asked to place this comment before the `</body>` tag on my site's main page:

`<!-- Last Update: 31/01/2006 -->`

I'd like to have the date auto-update after each new post.  I've been searching for the answer without success.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Ken

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called `get_lastpostdate( $timezone )`. Assuming your main page is a WordPress page this should do the job:

```
<!-- Last Update: <?php echo get_lastpostdate('server'); ?> -->
```